# Expand-7zip Foreach usage

Tags: powershell

Can someone please help me with `Expand-7Zip` `foreach` usage? As I see it's not a very popular way on the internet.

I want to unzip all *.zip files in a folder but cannot make it work. I tried something like

```
GCI | %{expand-7zip}
```

or tried to use `-ArchiveFileName` with a variable.

Previously I was using `Expand-Archive` but it crashes on the "path too long" problem. (some files have long names)

https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/PS7Zip/2.2.0/Content/Functions%5CExpand-7Zip.ps1

```
[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12
Install-PackageProvider -Name NuGet -MinimumVersion 2.8.5.201 -Force
Set-PSRepository -Name 'PSGallery' -SourceLocation "https://www.powershellgallery.com/api/v2" -InstallationPolicy Trusted
Install-Module -Name 7Zip4PowerShell -Force
```

Comment: How about `gci | Expand-7Zip`?

Comment: I also tried this. 
I get 
"
cmdlet Expand-7Zip at command pipeline position 2
Supply values for the following parameters:
(Type !? for Help.)
ArchiveFileName: 
"
Like it does not understand what comes via pipeline.

Comment: Please edit your post to include a link to `Expand-7Zip` documentation or source code.

Comment: Added. At least what I've found.

Comment: I believe this line works
`Get-ChildItem -Path $Path -Filter *.zip | %{Expand-7Zip -ArchiveFileName $_.FullName -TargetPath $Path}`

But I still get a problem with long names. It does not happen when I use 7zip via the context menu.

Looks like it's a PS problem.

Comment: Based on the error message, you're currently using `7Zip4PowerShell`'s `Expand-Zip` - have you tried the `PS7Zip` version?

Comment: Installed PS7Zip and ran the same command result is quite the same.

2 zip files are in a folder. As I see when it meets the long name file it moves to the next zip and then the same happens with the second one.

Comment: Does the long path issue persist when you use 7-zip command-line EXE directly?

Comment: I was about to write it.
When I use 7z.exe in PS there is no issue with the long path.

It appears only when I use PS modules or methods.